# Question regarding supermesh

Tags: current, dc, mesh-analysis

[image]So im trying to solve the folowing circuit using mesh analysis but i cant get the right results.Im trying to find the currents of mesh 4(down to the right) and mesh 1(left on the upperside).Ive determined that the current on mesh 3(lower on the left) is 10mA but i cant get the other results to be correct.Any help would be apreciated.

[image: Heres the what i have so far]

Comment: Can you supply us with any of your work product? Anything at all? For example, how did you calculate \$10\:\text{mA}\$?

Comment: What is your supermesh equation (i.e. the equation you made that combines two or more of the origital meshes into a supermesh)?

Comment: ive added a picture with what i have so far

Comment: @tpt98 Thanks so much. I will write up something, now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Verifying your claim of \$10\:\text{mA}\$ for the lower-left quadrant

Here's my ***marked-up*** version of your schematic:

[image]

Before I delve too much into a general solution, let's verify your assertion about \$I_3=10\:\text{mA}\$. It's not hard to do and you are right about that.

By inspection, you know that \$V_x=R_5\cdot\left(I_4-I_2\right)\$. But also by inspection, you know that \$g\cdot V_x=I_4-I_3\$. And from the problem statement, you know that \$I_2=I_s\$. So it must be that: \$g\cdot R_5\cdot\left(I_4-I_2\right)=I_4-I_3\$. Since \$g\cdot R_5=1\$, given your problem statement, this means \$I_4-I_2=I_4-I_3\quad\therefore I_3=I_2\$. And as \$I_2=I_s=10\:\text{mA}\$, you have your answer that \$I_3=10\:\text{mA}\$.

So I completely agree with your finding for the above reasoning.

### General Solution

Now, we could use that fact to reduce the above problem somewhat and find the rest. But I don't want to do that. I want to take a very general approach to the above problem and solve it, generally. It's better to avoid using special-case findings, as above, because if you learn the general approaches well, you don't need to waste time finding all the nooks and crannies of a particular circuit to simplify it. Instead, you just use very solid, bullet-proof methods that will consistently grind out good results time after time after time.

So let's just ***grind-out*** the mesh equations. I will take each successive quadrant by starting out at the lower-left node of the loop, assigning that node voltage the value of \$0\:\text{V}\$, and then work around the loop to develop the equation. I'll do this for all four loops.

$$\begin{align*}
0\:\text{V}+V_s-R_1\cdot I_1-R_3\cdot\left(I_1-I_2\right)-R_2\cdot\left(I_1-I_3\right)&=0\:\text{V}\\0\:\text{V}-R_3\cdot\left(I_2-I_1\right)-R_4\cdot I_2+V_{\text{I}_S}-R_5\cdot\left(I_2-I_4\right)&=0\:\text{V}\\0\:\text{V}-r\cdot \left(I_x=I_4\right)-R_2\cdot\left(I_3-I_1\right)-V_{g\,V_x}&=0\:\text{V}\\0\:\text{V}+V_{g\,V_x}-R_5\cdot\left(I_4-I_2\right)-R_6\cdot I_4&=0\:\text{V}
\end{align*}$$

Now, we know one more thing from the earlier analysis above:

$$g\cdot R_5\cdot\left(I_4-I_2\right)=I_4-I_3$$

So this provides five equations. Since we already are given \$I_s=I_2=10\:\text{mA}\$ in the problem specifications, we have these five unknowns to solve: \$I_1\$, \$I_3\$, \$I_4\$, \$V_{\text{I}_S}\$, and \$V_{g\,V_x}\$.

Let's use sympy:

```
var('r1 r2 r3 r4 r5 r6 r g is i1 i2 i3 i4 vgx vis vs')
eq1=Eq(0+vs-r1*i1-r3*(i1-i2)-r2*(i1-i3),0)
eq2=Eq(0-r3*(i2-i1)-r4*i2+vis-r5*(i2-i4),0)
eq3=Eq(0-r*i4-r2*(i3-i1)-vgx,0)
eq4=Eq(0+vgx-r5*(i4-i2)-r6*i4,0)
eq5=Eq(g*r5*(i4-i2),i4-i3)
ans=solve([eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4,eq5],[i1,i3,i4,vgx,vis])
for x in ans:x,ans[x].subs({r1:1e3,r2:500,r3:1e3,r4:1e3,r5:1e3,r6:1e3,r:1e3,g:.001,vs:20,i2:10e-3})
(i3, 0.0100000000000000)
(vgx, -2.00000000000000)
(vis, 12.0000000000000)
(i1, 0.0140000000000000)
(i4, 0.00400000000000000)
```

Here indeed, you can see that \$I_3=10\:\text{mA}\$. We knew this, already. But this just confirms it, but from a far more general approach to the problem.

Note that there was no need for a supermesh. There never is. Just as with KCL and nodal, there never is a need for a supernode. They are always superfluous.